# Is it possible to change variable during running of script?

Tags: lua

Im new into lua, I have this code :

```
a="1"
b="2"
c=
```

Is it possible to somehow define c as a+b?

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean with `a+b`?

If you want to add the numbers in both strings and get a number simply do

```
c = a + b
```

This implicitly does

```
c = tonumber(a) + tonumber(b)
```

This only works if a and b represent numbers! Lua will convert the strings to numbers prior to calcuating the sum.

If you want the sum as a string simply do

```
c = tostring(a+b)
```

If you want to concatenate both strings use the concatenation operator `..`

```
c = a .. b
```

This will result in `c` being `"12"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. With:

```lua
c = a + b
```

The two values will be added, and `3.0` will be stored in `c` at runtime.

Comment: No! - ;-) - ```a``` and ```b``` are datatype ```string```. The concatenation of strings is done with the two dots ```..``` and the metamethod is: ```__concat```. See: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.6

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi Lua will automatically convert a and b to numbers in this case so c = a + b is fine. Of course this will fail if a and b do not represent numbers.

Comment: Yes you are right. But its essential for a coder to know how to handle different datatypes. Therefore i upvote your answer. It handles and describe the differences ;-)

Comment: @Piglet's is definitely more in-depth yeah. OP asked about the `+` operator so I explained that and not concatenation, but it is possible they were confusing the two operators.